# Crashlytics doesn't catch SIGSEGV in Android

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

Today we found that Crashlytics don't catch SIGSEGV crashes, but google play console does. We were quite surprised to see many of such crashes in play console.

We want to have our crash reporting in one place. Can we catch SIGSEGV crashes with crashlytics?

Comment: Are you using the Crashlytics NDK SDK?

Comment: Should I?
I don't have any native code just 3rd party libraries which cause that.
Google play console does it by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard Android Crashlytics SDK catches Java crashes. Since SIGSEGV is a native crash you'll also need to include the Crashlytics NDK SDK, whether the SIGSEGV originates in an app's native libraries or third-party libraries. Check out https://fabric.io/downloads/gradle (with the NDK toggle switch on) for setup instructions.